# What does the status column mean when I run yum repolist

Tags: centos, centos6, yum, repository

I'm trying to update my PHP version, using the [webtatic repo](https://webtatic.com/packages/php56/). I've successfully done it (using the exact steps in the link) above on a test VM server running on my machine at home, but when I try and do the same on my live server, it get an error saying `no package php56w available`.

Running `yum repolist` on both servers, my test server, under the status column for webtatic says `285`, but on my live server it says `43+242`. All I can think is on my test server, all 285 packages are available, but on my live server only 43 are available.

Am I correct in thinking that? If so, how can I make the other packages available too?

Both servers are running CentOS 6.5 (Final)

Comment: You could try "yum clean all", then check repolist again

Comment: I get the same output still after `clean all`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Status column shows the number of packages available in repository. In your case **(43+242)** means

```
Number of packages can be install(43)  + packages excluded(242)
```

It seems you have excluded some packages in webstatic configuration file. Check for the below line in /etc/yum.repos.d/webstatic.repo

```
exclude=php*
```

Comment or remove all excluded packages from webstatic.repo and run repolist again.

`/etc/yum.conf` can also contain excluded packages, so you may need to check this too.

Comment: I don't have any exludes in my .repo file. Here are it's contents http://pastebin.com/fQN7FSey

Comment: You may have to check one more file for excluded packages /etc/yum.conf

Comment: A-ha! Found it, it was in yum.conf. Thanks :)